# Blender crashes when using any kind of normal map

Tags: normal-map

I have a low-poly model with some mottled texture baked into the normal map, however, when switching to "Viewport Shading" Blender crashes almost immediately if I try and move the model in any way (if I don't move anything it seems ok). It had no trouble *baking* the normal map, it's only when I try to *look* at a model that uses the normal map that I have the problem.

There are <strike>89</strike> 435 (accidentally applied decimate modifier) active faces in the model and the normal map is a 2k PNG texture. Un-hooking the normal map input on the Principled BSDF shader seems to make the problem go away (but then you have no normal map...)

It doesn't seem to matter whether I'm using EEVEE or Cycles. Turning off ambient occlusion in EEVEE seemed to prevent the crash.

My setup is a Xeon 2186m laptop with 32GB ram and a GTX1070 hooked up via thunderbolt and the latest nVidia Studio Drivers (the crash causes the graphics card to disconnect and it has to be re-plugged to work again). I've never had any other graphics issues with this setup.

This issue seems to be present on Blender 2.83 and 2.90.1. I'm guessing the fact that it's dying with such a simple model means there's something wrong with one or more of my model settings but I have no idea where to even start. Unfortunately I don't have another PC to test with and I've not seen this issue before (although this is my first time working with a homemade normal map).

***How do I go about tracing the source of an issue like this?***

[image]

Edit: Packed textures into .blend file

Edit 2/10/2020: After some more fault finding, it looks like it was being cause by a GPU power integrity problem, dialing the GPU power limit right back below stock seems to have fixed the issue, I might need to stick some extra bypass caps on the card

Comment: The textures are not packed in your file.

Comment: @lemon I hadn't even considered that they would not be part of the blend file, I've fixed that now

Comment: @lemon OK, I think I've packed it properly now, I'm getting a little "unpack item" icon when on the UV editor. Not my best start

Comment: No crash here... are your GPU drivers up to date?

Comment: @lemon Yeah, I tried updating to the newest version of the nVidia studio drives but no good, just tried it before and blender died the instant I clicked shaded view. The packed version lasted a couple seconds longer than ususal but still dies

Comment: Hello :). Works just fine for me. You can try [older Blender versions](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/), to see if it helps.

Comment: Does the crash still happen after some time? I'm curious why there seem to be the same problems here

Comment: @NoobCat I'm now pretty sure the problem was due to a power integrity issue with the power supply for my graphics card. Sometimes when the card has a sudden jump in utilisation the PSU wouldn't be fast enough, the voltage would dip and glitch the card. I originally though it might have been something in Blender because sometimes I could spend hours in Blender then when switching to rendered view with some models it'd crash but it looks like it had nothing to do with Blender. Power integrity problems are always a nightmare to diagnose 